# Decoding binary version of pdf from REST api call response using Powershell

Tags: rest, api, powershell, scripting

I have a powershell script where I send a call to REST Api:

```
$DownloadReportResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $DownloadReportUrl -ContentType "application/json" -Body $DownloadReportRequestBody | Out-File -FilePath ("C:\Practice\Report-01_29_14-28.pdf")  -Force
```

The response I get is a binary representation of the pdf, so it is bunch of texts:

```
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
  /N 3
  /Length 11 0 R
  /Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
xwXSçÇßsNö`$!l{¥@ ¦Ù¢  $÷@T°¢¨ÈR)X°ZÔ(âÞ
RZ¬âÂÑD§õööÞÛÛïç|ßûû½çý÷y ¤L®0V@(#ü½±qñì `= nn¶WXX0+ÐÍÈ;Ñ« R¼¯1{ÿOªÜl± (LÎ³xü\®ä/ÉVØ'åLKÎP0R°X~@9k(8u­?ûÌ°§yBOÎrÎæ  y
îó<)_Î"â<?_Î×ål)
äüF+äsä9 H
```

The Out-File -FilePath ("C:\Neoload\Report-01_29_14-28.pdf") command will save it as a pdf but when I open it I have no luck seeing the content.

**Question**: What commands are used to decoding the api response which sends pdf in binary representation and how do I go about saving it in my machine?

Comment: Use `Invoke-RestMethod`'s `-OutFile` argument. `Invoke-RestMethod @args -OutFile 'C:\Temp\download.pdf'`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 is there difference in putting "@args" ?

Comment: I used that syntax just to represent whatever args you're using.

Comment: Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $DownloadReportUrl -ContentType "application/json" -Body $DownloadReportRequestBody | Out-File -FilePath ("C:\Practice\Report-01_29_14-28.pdf")  -Force . That is what I am using, the file is being saved as .pdf but when I open I am getting error reading it in Adobe Reader. There's an encoding issue.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$DownloadReportResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $DownloadReportUrl -ContentType "application/json" -Body $DownloadReportRequestBody -OutFile "C:\Users\demo\download.pdf"
```

[Documentation Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.2#example-2--run-a-post-request)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Below one is working for me when downloading files from Box.com to local machine:
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Method Get **-OutFile** 'E:\NewfileName.pdf'
instead of
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $headers -Method Get **| Out-File** 'E:\NewfileName.pdf'

Mark as Answer if issue resolved.